# GPU computing in matlab

Tags: matlab, gpu

My matlab version is 2014a. Norm function is built in gpuArray function in matlab. I think it should return gpuArray class when input is gpuArray. But in my matlab, it returns double. Could anyone tell me what happened?

Example,

```
a=gpuArray.randn(3,4);
b=norm(a)
```

the type of b is "double" instead of "gpuArray".

Thank you

Comment: Could I ask: does this cause you any problems in your code, or is it simply an inconsistency you've observed?

Comment: It doesn't cause problem. I am just not sure if this inconsistency will slow down my code if I put it in the loop. It seems like to transfer back and forth between CPU and GPU every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately as you observe this is an inconsistency in the implementation of `gpuArray`. Generally speaking, methods that return data related to the values of the input array such as `min`, `max`, `sum` etc. return values as `gpuArray`, but `norm` does not.

Comment: Will this slow down my code if I put it in my loop?

Comment: Operations on scalars are generally faster on the CPU, so I recommend avoiding putting scalar data onto the GPU.  So actually this behaviour is probably beneficial if inconsistent.